# How to use JFrame to display strings and read input?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to display this code on a window. Now it is coming on the bottom side of Eclipse so I am planning to display on `JFrame`.  Is there any possibility to do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("INPUT A NUMER TO DISPLAY");

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        int num=scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("THE ENTERED NUMBER IS "     +num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: Or more generally, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: You could also have a look at [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this using a `JFrame`. But since it is just one input, you can do it using `JOptionPane` easily.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INPUT A NUMER TO DISPLAY");
        int input = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        System.out.println("User input: " + input);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User entered " + input);

    }
}
```

This is a simple implementation using a JFrame.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Input will appear here");

        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = textField.getText();
                System.out.println("Input: " + input);

                label.setText(input);
            }
        });

        container.add(textField);
        container.add(okButton);
        container.add(label);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Swing GUIs should be created and manipulated on the EDT. 2) A combination rich client / command prompt app. typically raises more problems than it solves. 3) I got the impression the OP wanted to both accept input **and show output** on the frame itself.

Comment: i want to do it in a jframe because i want to increase the size of the frame

Comment: but the system.out is not coming in the Jframe , can i do like that ?

Comment: @JaisonJoseph: You can display the input(or processed input) in a JLabel. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Friend, i am a beginner in java, it is helpd me a lot

Comment: can u suggest a ebook to study java completely ,

Comment: You are welcome :) Glad to hear my answer helped you. **Head First Java** and **Java for Dummies** are really good books for beginners.